# Display a varying popup image on text mouseover with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am building a page with a restaurant menu that will consist of a few different html tables that will store the item name in the first `<td>` in each `<tr>`. I would like a JavaScript function to run when the user hovers the mouse over the item name (the first `<td>` in each `<tr>`) that will display an image popup in a box that corresponds to the particular item name.

All together there will be roughly 40 different item names that need to have this mouse-over effect to display a quick pop up of the image that relates to the item name and then fade back out when the hover effect is no longer active. Some item names may not have an image available though.

### My question:

I am unsure what the best possible solution is to perform this or how to go about performing this. I have seen a few different techniques through Google that allow a image pop up when "mousing-over" a smaller image or a link, but would the same be possible with "mousing-over" text in a `<td>`?

- **Should I just use something like this:**
  `<td onmouseover="popup('<img src='/image/location/image.jpg>'')" onmouseout="popout()">1st Item Name</td>`
  Then use this:
  `<script type="text/javascript"> var pop = document.getElementById('popup'); </script`
- **Or** is it possible I could use (table / td) id names with a javascript array to call the correct images into their respective names in the `<td>'s`
- **Or** any other way that I am unable to think of / know about?

Here is the html I have so far for the table(s):

```
    <div id="first_food_table">
    <table border="0" bordercolor="" style="background-color:" width="750">
    <tr>
      <td>1st item name</td> <!--Image popup should be displayed when mouse-over text-->
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blahblah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2nd item name</td><!-- Different image popup here as well -->
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blahblah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3rd item name</td> <!-- Again a different image popup here as well-->
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blahblah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4th item</td> <!-- And so on and so forth -->
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blahblah</td>
    </tr>
    </table>        
    </div> 
    <div id="second_food_table>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1st item name</td>
      <td>Table Cell</td>
      <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2nd item name</td>
      <td>Table Cell</td>
      <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3rd item name</td>
      <td>Table Cell</td>
      <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4th item name</td>
      <td>Table Cell</td>
      <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Please explain which method you would use or you know of to perform this task. Also any JavaScript functions that are available to perform this or to display the image in a small popup window that will then fade away on mouseout.

Comment: _"I have seen a few different techniques through Google that allow a image pop up when "mousing-over" a smaller image or a link, but would the same be possible with "mousing-over" text in a <td>?"_ - Yes, exactly the same code should work for a td (or div or span or any other element type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have been using recently for these sort of things is to append a data- attibute to the element that is firing the event. So in this case your TD. Here is a link to the HTML 5 standard which describes the use of data attributes

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

You could have something like this in your td

```
<td data-imgsrc="imgfoler/specificimg.jpg">The item name</td>
```

Then in your javascript you get the value of the attribute like this:

```
var imgsrc = element.getAttribute('data-imgsrc');
```

I strongly recommend you learn a bit of jQuery to link this all together is it will make your life infinitely easier. Otherwise you can continue on in plain javascript.

**in jQuery (includes fading box easily)**

HTML

```
<td data-imgsrc="imgfoler/specificimg.jpg">The item name</td>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td[data-imgsrc]').mouseenter(function() {
        var imgsrc = $(this).attr('data-imgsrc');
        $('img#id_of_your_image_element').attr('src',imgsrc).show();
    });
    $('td[data-imgsrc]').mouseleave(function() {
        $('img#id_of_your_image_element').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

**Or in plain javascript**

HTML

```
// You need to add an onclick handler on every td
<td data-imgsrc="imgfoler/specificimg.jpg" onmouseover="swapimg(this);">
    The item name
</td>
```

JS

```
function swapimg(element) {
    var imgsrc = element.getAttribute('data-imgsrc');
    var imgelement = document.getElementById('id_of_your_image_element');
    imgelement.setAttribute('src',imgsrc);

    // No fading out here, if you want fading just use jQuery. Fading
    // in native JS is a pain in the behind.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have seen JQuery used just never used it in depth on my own. Now its my understanding that Jquery can not start to load until everything else is loaded (images, banners, etc..) If I would use the `data-imgsrc="imgfolder/image.jpg"` inside the TD, will all of the images referenced throughout the page have to "load" in the background before the mouseover effect would work? Thanks again for the help, I'm going to continue to look into Jquery some more.

Comment: It is true that the images would have to load in the background if you wanted them immediately, but this is not jQuery specific as you will need to do this for normal javascript as well. jQuery can be used before everything is loaded (as long as jQuery is loaded), it is just the $(document).ready() function which is a safety net to prevent you manipulating DOM elements that don't exist yet. Here's a good article about using jQuery before the document ready state http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Comment: And like I said in my answer, if you want fading use jQuery. Making it work for all browsers in native javascript is ridiculously frustrating. Believe me, I've tried. Of course jQuery isn't your only options, theres a bunch of different frameworks that do cool stuff for you like fading. Prototype, MooTools etc but I would say personally, jQuery has the smallest learning curve.

Comment: Yea you have definitely persuaded me to continue to use jquery mainly because of all the time it seems it can save you whether with this project or others. In the function what do you mean when you reference `'img#id_of_your_image_element'` Should i set a `<td id="">` or do I need a html div setup to display the image properly. I tried to use `'td'` inside of the `'img#id_of_your_image_element'` and all of the TD's fade away on mouseover and no image is displayed and they do not return when mouseenter is not active. I understand why it doesnt work but am unsure of what to use there instead.

Comment: The `img#id_of_of_your_image` is the id of the actual place that you want to show your image. If you want it to be a popup, it will probably be an image element contained in a absolutely positioned div or something similar. If you add your html to show what element your image is being displayed in, I will append my answer to show how you would do that.

Comment: I don't necessarily have an element to display the image in. If I just wanted it to display near the `<td>` that is calling the image Would I have to have a `<div>` near every `<td>` or could I have a `<div>` that will hold the image displayed next to or directly above the `<td>` that is displaying the image? I don't want to have a separate placeholder on the page(ie. above the table) because the page will be quite long with about 40 or so `<td>`'s. If there was a way to just display the image directly to the right of the `<td>` that is being "moused-over", wouldn't matter if it is ---cont.

Comment: covering other `<td>`'s to the right of the `<td>` with the mouse over because the image will fade away when 'mouseenter' is no longer active anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: Well this is more heading towards the HTML, CSS side of things. In theory you only need 1 image element. I would place it inside of a div (so that if additional info is needed in the popup later you can add it). The div is set to `display:hidden; position: absolute (or fixed);` Then what you do is calculate where the td is on the page and set the `top` and `left` attributes of the div to place it close to the td. Then change use jQuery show() or fadeIn(). If you don't know much about this there are hundreds of tooltip plugins for jquery which should do the trick.